Is there a way to get the user that activated the scaffolder template?
I have a scaffolder template in backstage and I want to log information about the user:
e.g.
apiVersion: scaffolder.backstage.io/v1beta3
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: hello-world-template
  title: Hello World
  description: Says Hello to the user that triggered the template.
spec:
  owner: engineering
  type: service

  parameters: []
  steps:
    - id: log-hello
      name: Say hello to the logged in user
      action: debug:log
      input:
        message: Hello <what do I put here>


Try this:
apiVersion: scaffolder.backstage.io/v1beta3
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: hello-world-template
  title: Hello World
  description: Says Hello to the user that triggered the template.
spec:
  owner: user:default/punkle
  type: service

  parameters: []
  steps:
    - id: log-hello
      name: Say hello to the logged in user
      action: debug:log
      input:
        message: Hello ${{ user.ref }}

